# How do I set Yes or No value in my template PhpWord instead of 1 or 0?

Tags: laravel, checkbox, phpword, setvalue

I have a form and a template with format .docx
The proccess of replacing variables in the templates is working well except the checkbox. In the value checkbox I have **1** and **0**.
Now instead of boolean value (0 or 1), i want to have **Yes** and **No.**
My controller here:

```
      public function edit(Stagiaire $stagiaire, $downloadName = null)
{
    $id = $stagiaire ->id;
    $desc1 = Stagiaire::find($id);

    $my_template = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor(public_path('templateStagiaire.docx'));

    $my_template->setValue('id', $desc1->id);
    $my_template->setValue('civilite', $desc1->civilite);
    $my_template->setValue('prenoms', $desc1->prenoms);
    $my_template->setValue('nom', $desc1->nom);

    //This 3 inputs are checbox in my form
    $my_template->setValue('regles_deonto', $desc1->regles_deonto);
    $my_template->setValue('reglement_interieur', $desc1->reglement_interieur);
    $my_template->setValue('horaires', $desc1->horaires);
    
    //The name of my file
    $first_name = $stagiaire->prenoms ;
    $last_name = $stagiaire->nom ;
    $filename = $first_name. " ". $last_name;
    

    try{
        $my_template->saveAs(storage_path("$filename.docx"));
    }catch (Exception $e){
        //handle exception
    }
    $downloadName = $downloadName??$filename;

    return response()->download(storage_path("$filename.docx"));
    }
```

My form

```
    <div id="container">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="regles_deonto" id="regles_deonto" value="1" required 
    > Régles déontologies
                    <input type="checkbox" name="reglement_interieur" id="reglement_interieur" 
    value="1" required > Réglement Intérieur

                    <input type="checkbox" name="horaires" id="horaires" value="1" required > 
    Horaires
    </div>
```

My Question is how can I replace the booleans values (0 and 1) by Yes or No in my template Word.
I need help please.
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do like this,

```
//This 3 inputs are checbox in my form
    $desc1->regles_deonto = (bool)($desc1->regles_deonto) == true ? 'Yes' : 'No'; 
    $my_template->setValue('regles_deonto', $desc1->regles_deonto);
```

You can do this similarly for other two values.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `(bool)` to cast your input to a boolean and use conditional statement to get 'Yes' or 'No':

```php
//This 3 inputs are checbox in my form
$my_template->setValue('regles_deonto', (bool) $desc1->regles_deonto ? 'Yes' : 'No');
$my_template->setValue('reglement_interieur', (bool) $desc1->reglement_interieur ? 'Yes' : 'No');
$my_template->setValue('horaires', (bool) $desc1->horaires ? 'Yes' : 'No');
```

Comment: Thanks Hafez Divandari. it seems to be the same proposition of bhucho. I do this and it's working well. Thank you very much